# ForEach console error with array list using translate

Tags: angular, arraylist

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Hi, I've got this error. I've created a function which is suppose to translate array based on json path. What am I doing wrong?

```
menu = [
        {title: 'MyPath'},
        {title: 'MyPath'},
        {title: 'MyPath'},
        {title: 'MyPath'},
        {title: 'MyPath'},
    ];

    translating(menu ): Array<any> {
        menu .forEach((menuItem) => {
            menuItem.title = this.translateService.instant(menuItem.title);
        });
        return menu ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i added some additions to your code, this should work now:

```
menu = [
        {title: 'MyPath'},
        {title: 'MyPath'},
        {title: 'MyPath'},
        {title: 'MyPath'},
        {title: 'MyPath'},
    ];

  const translating = menu =>  {
        menu.forEach((menuItem) => {
            // do sth with your service
        });
        
        return menu ;
    }
```